# Electronic component identification

Tags: integrated-circuit

I bought electronic components but I have doubts. Part Number TC1015-1.8VCT713 with A59S marking and TK71638SIL with L3B marking.

It's good?
Thanks

[image: strong text]**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If that marking is indeed L3B (and not L38) then it's more like an LP5951MF-1.8 LDO.
Whereas the marking A59S seems to suggest rather the [TC1014](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21335e.pdf) part from Microchip.

Comment: Agree with you, I was thinking of TC1014-3.3VCT713 and for the other it' possible for LP5951MF-1.8 LDO.

Comment: I checked for L3B and finally I think LP5951MG-1.8

Comment: LP5951MG is a SC-70 package whilst the LP5951MF is a SOT23. Well in any case I guess you got the right answer pretty much 95%. Feel free to indicate if this answered your question or if it was useful at least .. cheers ;-)